# No logro hacer que se muestre la imagen de usuario

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, login

Estoy haciendo un sistema de login y ahora mismo estoy en la parte de las imágenes de usuario, el problema es que al momento de subir la imagen esta si se sube a la carpeta correspondiente y también se agrega la ruta en la base de datos, pero al momento de querer imprimir el resultado con 'echo' no se muestra nada y por lo tanto tampoco se muestra la imagen. Adjunto parte de mi código por si alguien me puede ayudar.

```
    <?php session_start(); 
    $foto = $_SESSION['foto'];
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    include 'php/conexion.php';
    $consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$id'");
    $valores = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
    $nombre = $valores['nombre'];
    $email = $valores['email'];
    $foto = $valores['foto'];
    ?>
```

```
 <span class="image">
<!--aquí es donde deberia cargar la ruta de la imagen, pero no lo hace-->
                    <img src=<?php ; echo $foto; ?>">
                </span>


            </div>
            <!-- cambiar imagen perfil--->
            <div>
             <form action="foto.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?>" style=" border: none; display: block;">
                 <input type="file" name="nfoto">
                 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Actualizar</button>
            </form>
          <!-- cambiar imagen perfil --->
```

Comment: Bien, antes de nada, podrías mostrar si te da algún error?, desde la consola o insertando en el archivo php lo siguiente arriba del todo:
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: ¿Seguro que en `$foto` tienes **la ruta completa y correcta** de la imagen?

Comment: Estás obteniendo el usuario filtrando por `email = '$id'`, entonces me pregunto si efectivamente usas el email como `$id`, o por el contrario deberías filtrar por `id = '$id'`. En cualquier caso, deberías comprobar si la consulta realmente te devuelve alguna fila o no. Echar un ojo al error_log, o activar `display_errors`, también te ayudaría a depurar.

Comment: @DavidGonzalo ya puse lo que me comentaste en el archivo php y el error que me sale es el siguiente: Notice: Undefined index: foto in /storage/ssd2/904/19580904/public_html/panel.php on line 15 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /storage/ssd2/904/19580904/public_html/panel.php on line 20 Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /storage/ssd2/904/19580904/public_html/panel.php on line 21

Comment: @A.Cedano he comprobado que la ruta sea la completa y correcta en la base de datos y he visto que si.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP entiendo, voy a comprobar si el error deriva de esa línea o no.

Comment: Hola a todos, ya pude solucionar el error, hice el cambio que @JoséCarlosPHP me menciono aparte en la rúta de la imagen cambie: <img src="<?php echo $_SESSION['foto'];?>"> por <img src="<?php ; echo $foto; ?>"> muchas gracias a todos por tomarse el tiempo de responder.

Comment: Para futuras preguntas, pon el código como lo tienes. En la pregunta ya tenías `echo $foto;` según el código de la pregunta. Lo de `echo $_SESSION['foto'];` no sé de dónde lo sacas, por eso te pregunté si en `$foto` tenías la ruta correcta y completa de la imagen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás obteniendo el usuario filtrando por `email = '$id'`, entonces me pregunto si efectivamente usas el email como `$id`, o por el contrario deberías filtrar por `id = '$id'`. En cualquier caso, deberías comprobar si la consulta realmente te devuelve alguna fila o no. Echar un ojo al error_log, o activar `display_errors`, también te ayudaría a depurar.

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '" . (int)$id . "'");
```

**Nota**.- Además he casteado `$id` a entero (int) para asegurarme de que que no fastidia la query.

Comment: Muchas gracias, efectvamente ese era el error, te agradezo mucho que te hayas tomado el tiempo de responder.

Comment: @DaniDaniel De nada, en tal caso por favor acepta la respuesta.